# Xamarin.Forms: Start an activity using DependencyService

Tags: c#, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms.Page I have a DependencyService that must activate an activity in my .Droid project. How do I activate the Activity?
I've tried

```
StartActivity(typeof(FacebookActivity));
```

but I get

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Exception of type
>   'Java.Lang.NullPointerException' was thrown.

What do I have to initialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the problem. I have to put an explicit constructor

```
public FacebookActivity(){}
```