# How can I launch a Android Activity from Xamarin Forms Page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I know that i can launch a Xamarin Forms page from an Native Android Activity, but how do i start a Native Android Activity from Xamarin Forms ContentPage. I tried with DependencyService but without success.

Comment: Custom page renderer ?

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874892/xamarin-forms-start-an-activity-using-dependencyservice

Comment: I created a DependencyService Interface and connected it to a function in my Activity in Android. But i can not Start another activity from that function and also i can not set the contentView from outside onCreate method. What am i doing wrong? The error is: The name 'StartActivity' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Here is a correct and 
complete answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338217/start-an-android-activity-in-xamarin-forms/44339481#44339481

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

First i needed to create a Interface like this in Xamarin Project

```
public interface IRecordVideoPage
{
    void StartNativeIntentOrActivity();
}
```

then i launched the Native Android Activity from my Xamarin Forms Content Page using Dependency Service like this:

```
DependencyService.Register<IRecordVideoPage>();
DependencyService.Get<IRecordVideoPage>().StartNativeIntentOrActivity();
```

next I created a RecordActivity class in my Android Project that loads the Test Activity

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(RecordActivity))]
namespace StreamTest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "RecordActivity")]
    public class RecordActivity : IRecordVideoPage
    {
        public void StartNativeIntentOrActivity()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(Test));
            Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

finally I set the content view in the Test class:

```
public class Test : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public Test() { }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Record);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is the way. I think you don't need that     'DependencyService.Register<IRecordVideoPage>();' code, Xamarin do the job for you.

Comment: This is right way to start activity, i tried and working fine for start splash activity

Answer (score 1):

DependencyService is your best option. The concept behind PCL (Portable Class Library) is exactly to be platform independet.
Maybe we can help if you show the error you are getting with Dependency Service